# how to filter or Extract the file from directory?

Tags: bash, shell, filenames

I have files in format below:

```
abc_abc_abc   
abc_abc_abc.1    
abc_bca_bca    
abc_bca_bca.1    
abc_bca_bca.2    
abc_cab    
abc
```

I want to get the files which is having 2 underscores and exclude other files like with . (dot) 
and single underscore.

The result would look like:

```
abc_abc_abc
abc_bca_bca
```

Comment: What are you planning to use the filenames for? This matters as it may affect how one goes about generating them.

Comment: Could you potentially have a file named `xyz_qrs_t.1` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find . -name "*_*_*" -not -name "*.*"
```

This will search in subdirectories also. If you don't want this, add `-maxdepth 1` and maybe `-type f` if you only want regular files:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*_*_*" -not -name "*.*"
```

Add `-printf "%P\n"` to get rid of the preceding `./`.

Answer (score 0):

With `ksh`, `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob` using some double-negations  (here assuming you also want to exclude files with 3 or more underscores):

```
printf '%s\n' !(!(*_*_*)|*_*_*_*|*.*)
```

With `zsh -o extendedglob` and its `~` *except* operator:

```
printf '%s\n' *_*_*~(*_*_*_*|*.*)
```

or using `zsh`'s native negation operator:

```
printf '%s\n' ^(^*_*_*|*_*_*_*|*.*)
```

If you still want the files with more than 2 underscores, that's just `!(!(*_*_*)|*.*)` or `*_*_*~*.*` or `^(^*_*_*|*.*)` in place of the above, respectively.

Other approaches could be `!(*[._]*)_!(*[._]*)_!(*[._]*)` (replace `[_.]` with `.` to allow 3 or more underscore).

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically, in bash (or shells that support arrays:

```
files=(???_???_???)
```

This uses the `?` globbing character to pick up files named as you've shown, with 3 characters, an underscore, 3 characters, an underscore, then 3 characters. This could be foiled if you have a filename such as `xyz_qrs_t.1`, though.

A little more refined would be:

```
files=([^._][^._][^._]_[^._][^._][^._]_[^._][^._][^._])
```

... which uses the `[^ ... ]` [globbing syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching). Each `[^._]` asks for one character that is *not* a period or underscore. Mixed in there are two underscores, separating three batches of three `[^._]`.

Loop over them with:

```
for f in "${files[@]}"; do printf "File: %s\n" "$f"; done
```